# Is it possible to automatically add people to a Google+ circle by their Google Profile ID?

Tags: google-plus

I have exported a list of profile IDs I've been following on Google Reader. Is it possible to import them as a circle in Google+?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nicolla Barozzi answered this on [Quora](http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-automatically-make-a-Google-Plus-circle-of-the-people-I-was-following-in-Google-Reader):

**[Get your reader friends back](http://reader.alfonsosiloniz.es/)** - *Obtain one circle from your old Google Reader interface*

> - Go to the import/export page Google let you to get a JSON file with the people you followed (following.json) and with the people were following you (followers.json). The link is [here](http://www.google.com/reader/settings?display=import) and download the two last ones that you see in the following image to your computer
>     [image]
> - Create a "Reader" Circle (or similar name) in Google+ so you can import these contacts in it.
> - If you use Google Chrome, there is an extension that it is very useful. You will obtain from this page a series of profiles links to G+ for those people. The extension Circle+ ([Link to Chrome Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lgejhoiengobafehdiejgcdnogdngeej)) will be able to add all those links automagically to any circle you have in G+. If you don't use Chrome you can follow all the links one by one to add them to a G+ circle, so I encourage you to download Google Chrome and Circle+